# package or namespace load failed for ‘googleLanguageR’

Tags: r, speech-to-text, google-language-api

I am facing issue to install "googleLanguageR" package in R version 3.5

I have installed Rtools to install that

> library(googleLanguageR)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘googleLanguageR’ in gzfile(file, "rb"):
>    cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: package ‘googleLanguageR’ was built under R version 3.5.3 
>   2: In gzfile(file, "rb") :
>     cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/datacore/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/memoise/Meta/nsInfo.rds', probable reason 'Invalid argument'

Comment: Check your R version, if it is lower, upgrade. If it is higher, you'll need an archive of the package. Also do you have permission to write onto the drive? Are you on a remote pc?

Comment: @NelsonGon - Thanks for checking those points. The error was only due to permission to write onto. 
Now it's successfully installed in my other machine. Thank you so much !!

Comment: Welcome, good to know.